# Map home folder to map docker volume to local storage

Tags: docker, mapping, volumes, tatum.io

Im a massive noob when it comes to backend dev-ops stuff, but I'm trying to setup a KMS provided by Tatum.io that let's you sign transactions with private keys. Everything seems straightforward except for this one step in their [Github repo](https://github.com/tatumio/tatum-kms) that mentions mapping the home folder so that the docker volume is mapped to locale storage. Only problem is, I'm not really sure how to go about it. Could anyone help me understand what to do? The Docker docs they link to are not helpful to me at all (too much info to know where to start).

Answer (score 0):

The example command given in the docs already shows you how to do the volume mapping:

```bash
docker run -d --env-file .env -v $HOME:/root/.tatumrc tatumio/tatum-kms daemon
```

The docker volume is the `-v $HOME:/root/.tatumrc` flag provided to docker. It essentially maps the home directory on your host machine to a path in the container, so files will be available in both places. I say essentially, because I'm simplifying the details depending on how you're running Docker.

Comment: Thank you for this. From my understanding the command they give should be automatically mounting the $HOME folder to the /root/.tatumrc directory through the -v command. The problem is that is does not do this as when I go to use the commands, I get an error saying there is no storage path or password (the password is stored in the .env file in the $HOME folder).Im assuming that I get this error because the KMS is trying to access the password, but it’s not accessible because the volume is not mapped to the $HOME folder.

Comment: Yes, it should be mapping the local directory in the container. Do you have a `.env` file in your home directory or wherever you're running the `docker run` command? Perhaps the lefthand side of the volume command needs to be `$HOME/.tatumrc`?